# Tem alguma forma de debugar pelo navegador pra parar exatamente na linha que esta sendo executada?

Tags: javascript, navegador-de-internet, debug

Eu peguei um código complexo para manutenção e notei que uma tabela está atualizando constantemente causando lentidão na página.

Gostaria de saber se tem alguma opção dos navegadores(preferência chrome), que me permita parar a execução do javascript e ir pra linha atual que estava sendo executada.

A questão é que não sei a linha a ser debugada. Tem varios arquivos JS referenciados e suponho que tenha algum script rodando com um setTimeout.

Comment: Você pode acessar as ferramentas do desenvolvedor, simplesmente pressionando F12 no seu teclado. Para ele parar na linha desejada, basta por um breakpoint na linha, como em qualquer IDE de desenvolvimento.

Comment: Use a resposta do @EduardoBinotto mais utilize o botão de pause quando vc quer que ele pare onde ele esta executando

Comment: É isso mesmo, se ele complementar a resposta eu marco como correta

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sim, no chrome basta pressionar f12 e ir na aba sources e achar o arquivo que você quer debugar.

Para parar no momento exato que está executando o código use o botão pause marcado em vermelho na imagem.

Independente do arquivo que está sendo executado o chrome vai achar o mesmo e parar na linha correspondente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Apos adicionar o breakpoint pressione F10 para passar as linhas.

Comment: Editei a minha pergunta. Queria por exemplo se estiver rodando um loop parar exatamente na linha que está sendo executada pois desconheço o arquivo js que está sendo executado e a linha tb

Comment: Resposta Ajustada para sanar a duvida da sua pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Uma **outra solução** que pode ser mais prático que adicionar o breakpoint pelo inspetor, é usando a palavra:

```
debugger
```

Coloca isto e simplesmente abra o inspetor (F12), evitando ficar 'caçando' o arquivo para adicionar o breakpoint.